# I want to create the clusters of similar strings in the flowing array

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, nlp, pattern-matching

I have the array like

---

[ 
"/core/api/v2.0/wallet/62da5521930eaf0f2e855": 1,
"/core/api/v2.0/wallet/62da382894c5dd0f9ab11": 1,
"/core/api/v2.0/users/sync/603a9c6a-c686-42af-b5f7-1f5bcfd75": 1,
"/core/api/v2.0/users/sync/64c73c5b-e6cc-4f98-9c54-69e7c796a": 3,
"/core/api/v2.0/users/sync/c3dfe00d-3950-401b-b068-d64aac99f39c": 3,
"/core/api/v2.0/users/sync/32cd70c8-ca92-4075-bb2f-1b9d99527723": 2,
"/core/api/v2.0/users/sync/245b0029-c05b-4007-bacb-656db21c170e": 1,
"/core/api/v2.0/users/sync/9175d6a9-386c-4b0d-9db4-c6053913c354": 1,
"/core/api/v2.0/tools/generate/trigger-download": 22,
"/core/api/v2.0/tools/generate/search-photos": 17,
]

---

I want the results like

---

[
"/core/api/v2.0/wallet/:id": 2,
"/core/api/v2.0/users/sync/:id: 11 "
"core/api/v2.0/tools/generate/:tool-name": 39,
]

---

Answer (score 0):

just loop over array and keep counter if meets specific match likewise:

```
let wallet_match=0;
for (let i = 0; i < your_array.length; i++) {
    if(your_array[i].includes("/core/api/v2.0/wallet/")) {
       wallet_match+=1;
    }
}
```

analogically you can list for other matches as well!